# Query about accessing HttpOnly Cookie & Secure cookie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, single-page-application, restful-authentication

I am working on RESTful SPA app using angularJS. Currently initial REST call is setting a "token" cookie on **xyz.com** ( secured response cookie)  after successful user login.  I am not able to read this cookie in Javascript/angular as I am  working on localhost.

What I understood here , unless I run this app from xyz.com , i wont be able to access this cookie OR do I need a secured connection ?

Is my Understanding correct ?

Secondly, my understanding about "httponly" cookie is that , it wont be accessible from javascript even though you are on same host.

Please correct my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

As the author of a website:

- You cannot read a cookie for a different site (ever)
- You cannot read an HTTP Only cookie with JavaScript
- You cannot read a Secure cookie unless it is served over HTTPS

That's three separate conditions, with independent effects, and none, some or all of them can apply to any given cookie.

Therefore if a cookie is *secure* and *for a different site* then you can't read it no matter if you use HTTPS or not (since *different site* blocks you even if *secure* does not).

Comment: That means,  if I deploy app in same domain or subdomain it will give access to secured cookie Correct? .. I am bit confused about 3rd point you mentioned. I understood about httpOnly Cookie though.